# Update PostgreSQL hstore field with sql variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I have table `files` which has hstore column `details`. In my sql statement I insert data to it:

```
  UPDATE files SET details =  'new_users=>new_users_count'::hstore where id = v_file_id;
```

but I want to update this hstore field not with string but with variable that is available in my sql statement. How can I do this?

Comment: I gives me the following error:

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function hstore(unknown, integer) does not exist

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PL/pgSQL can't detect variables inside a string literal. You need to use the "constructor" method of the `hstore` type to pass a variable:

```
UPDATE files 
   SET details = hstore('new_users', p_new_user_count)
where id = v_file_id;
```

If `p_new_user_count` is defined as a number (rather than a `varchar` or `text`) you need to cast this to a text value:

```
UPDATE files 
   SET details = hstore('new_users', p_new_user_count::text)
where id = v_file_id;
```

**Edit** after the question was changed:

To do this for multiple variables you can either concatenate two hstore values:

```
details = hstore('new_users', p_new_user_count::text)||hstore('post_count', p_post_count::text)
```

or use arrays:

```
details = hstore(array['new_users','post_count'], array[p_user_count, p_post_count]::text[]);
```

This is all documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html

Comment: Your answer is great but I also have one question. How can I in this one update statement also add another key? For example:
posts_count => posts_count_variable?

Comment: @MateuszUrbański: see my edit - but it's not a good practice to change the question after you have received an answer.

Comment: I want to avoid creating the next question. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 6):

In case if you need to replace only **new_users** in the hstore then

```
UPDATE files 
SET details = details || hstore('new_users', p_new_user_count::text)
where id = v_file_id;
```

It will replace new_users if already present in the column or add a new entry.